# Using "Univ" / "=.." meta-predicate to return boolean result of a function?

Tags: prolog

I am trying to use a meta-predicate "=.." to return a value.

Now I have two examples below, the first one works
perfectly, however I cannot figure out how to do something similar using the second example:

Example 1:

```
?- Expression=..[+,2,3], Value is Expression.
Expression = 2 + 3
Value = 5
yes
```

Example 2:

```
?- test(N):-N>=0.
Term asserted

?- Term=..[test,-5], Value is Term.
```

This is producing an error, 
and i want Value to be yes or true or 1,
so that I can use it in an IF statement.

How can this be accomplished using the "univ" "=.." operators?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use `is/2` to get the boolean value of a predicate call. Use `call/1` instead:

```
?- Term =.. [test, -5], call(Term).
false.
?- Term =.. [test, 5], call(Term).
Term = test(5).
```

Or just:

```
?- call(test, 5).
true.

?- call(test, -5).
false.
```

Then your if-then-else just becomes:

```
(Term =.. [test, -5], call(Term) ->
    % then-part
;
    % else-part
)
```

If you want to reify the result value for some other reason, the usual advice applies:

```
(Term =.. [test, -5], call(Term) ->
    Value = true   % or 1
;
    Value = false  % or 0, or fail
)
```